# How can I search a specific word in between two sign to notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I’m new on Notepad++ and I want to know search a specific word in between two sign ?

I couldn't find the answer on the internet. I need your help.

Comment: In the notepad++ search window you can use regular expression. In the docs you can read how it works: https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/ If you need more help, please share an example of what you want to find.

Comment: https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/21308/how-to-find-and-select-all-words-between-select-words

Answer (score 0):

Open the Mark dialog ( Ctrl + M )

SEARCH (?s-i)(?<=WORD).+?(?=WORD)

Tick the two options Purge for each search and Wrap around

Un-tick all other box options

Select the Regular expression search mode

Click on the Mark All button